# How to use contains to compare property value from one array to another array logic app expression?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have two arrays variables and values like below

arraydata1 =

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "bbb"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "ccc"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "ddd"
  },
 {
    "id": "14",
    "name": "bbb"
  }
]
```

arraydata2 =

```
[
  {
    "id": "111",
    "tablename": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "id": "222",
    "tablename": "bbb"
  }
]
```

output -

```
[
       {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "aaa"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "bbb"
      },
     {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "bbb"
      },
    ]
```

using 2 foreach also i'm able to achieve this but it takes time to compare.

also tried using taken a `for-each connector` and inside that used `contains` expression to compare `name and tablename` but for all values it is false.

`contains(variables('arraydata2'),items('For_each')?['tablename'])`

> can we do it without using 2 foreach

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Updated to one for each loop:

The following will return 2 objects, you won't get the `true` reply but you will have the objects instead.

`items('For_each')['name']` and `item()['tablename']`

[image]

Comment: without using 2 foreach can we do it? and using above code it will set new value every time can we take all matched values into one array so that later we can use that variable

Comment: Using just one array? Well, no I don't think so. You somehow need to iterate through the index of the two arrays and on the `name` and `tablename`. Getting the value into another array after is easy. Updated answer.

Comment: @Neo I thought I tried this before and gave it another go. This works to only get the objects that contain what you are looking for with one for each-

Comment: problem with above solution is it is giving result of separate element in seperate array I want one array of result like in question

Comment: And you can appens the resultat from the filter action to your own array. Or as we did in another question, store it in an table for later use.

Comment: Will add new one :)